# Dynamic htaccess to redirect multiple URLs with numbers, letters and dashes

Tags: .htaccess

I'm changing a website structure, and now to keep all the 1000 live links I have around the web pointing to the right page, I'm trying to create an htaccess rule that makes an automatic redirection.
So basically, a rule that transforms URLs like this:

```
mysite.pt/web/pt/variable-directory/variablenumber-string-to-keep.html
```

Into:

```
mysite.pt/string-to-keep
```

The problem is that I'm unable to create a dynamic rule that catches all the URLs. I don't know much about regular expressions (which maybe would apply here?).

Below is where I'm at right now, a static and incomplete rule.

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.pt/[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.pt//$1 [r=301,nc]

//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 web/pt/variable-directory/variablenumber-string-to-keep.html string-to-keep/
```

The starting "web/pt/" and the last ".html" is always the same.
But "variable-directory" (which varies in lenght and number of words) and "variablenumber" (single number, can go up to 9999) changes from page to page.

I'm trying to remove these elements plus the extra dash after "variablenumber", only to keep the "string-to-keep" after mysite.pt/

"string-to-keep" also varies in length and number of words.

How can I accomplish this? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect` doesn't support regex and you can use a generic redirect rule like this using `mod_rewrite`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.pt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^web/pt/[^/]+/\d+-(.+)\.html$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Tyvm for your answer! Just one question regarding the code, and I hope you don't mind me asking this before testing it properly, but I get lost in the middle of that last line:  
Is it considering the "variablenumber" and the dash right after it as well? 
Thank you

Comment: `\d+-` will match any number followed by hyphen